# how registration Page in servlet

Tags: java, servlets

Java Servlet Code for inserting values into **registraion** table:

```
package mypackage;  

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement;

public class Register extends HttpServlet {


    static final String JDBC_DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    static final String DB_URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test";
    static final String USER = "root";
    static final String PASS = "";
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {


        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

        String name=request.getParameter("userName");
        String pass=request.getParameter("userPass");
        String email=request.getParameter("userEmail");
        String ccountry=request.getParameter("userCountry");

        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL, USER, PASS);

        stmt=conn.createStatement();
//      String sql="insert into test values(?,?,?,?)";
        java.sql.PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement("insert into registraion values(?,?,?,?)");

        ps.setString(1,name);
        ps.setString(2,pass);
        ps.setString(3,email);
        ps.setString(4,ccountry);
        int i=ps.executeUpdate();
        if(i>0)
        out.print("You are successfully registered...");


        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }



    }
}
```

In my table there are 5 field like below.

```
id(primary key ,auto generate)
name
pass
email
country
```

But its not inserting values into **registration** table. I need to insert values on registration table.

please help me.

Comment: Getting any error? Plz paste stacktrace here...

Comment: What do you mean by 'it isn't working'?  Does it throw an exception?  Does it compile?

Comment: Data is not inserting in database registraion table ...

Comment: @user2794306 But program will throw some error.. if something is wrong.

Comment: What is the error message you get?

Comment: Your table name is spelt incorrectly.  Does registraion exist?

Comment: NO Error But aftre clcik on Button it show HTTP Status 404 - /Registration/servlet/Register

Comment: Thats mapping issue you need to map your servlet in `web.xml`

Comment: registraion yes it there

Comment: To map your servlet check the following thread..

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8198312/servlet-mapping-using-web-xml

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
  <servlet>
    <servlet-name>RegisterServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>mypackage.Register</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>RegisterServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/Register</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>register.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>   check this please

Comment: I did same thing please check my code ...

Comment: Post your HTML code. Here.. and action URL is `/Register`

Comment: <html>
<body>
 <form action="servlet/Register" method="post">

  Name:<input type="text" name="userName" /><br />
  <br /> Password:<input type="password" name="userPass" /><br />
  <br /> Email Id:<input type="text" name="userEmail" /><br />
  <br /> Country: <select name="userCountry">
   <option>India</option>
   <option>Pakistan</option>
   <option>other</option>
  </select> <br />
  <br /> <input type="submit" value="register" />

 </form>
</body>
</html>

Comment: Change `action="servlet/Register"` to `action="/Register"`

Comment: Still Not work same issue can u  please tell me what is Problem

Comment: At the first `web-app` tag in `web.xml` there is a semi colon at the end. remove that... and try again by restarting server

Comment: Vicky i did But still issue can u please tell ur emal id so that i can send ur my Example

Comment: vicky.thakor@javaquery.com

Comment: please check ur mail.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the table name in insert statement is in wrong spell.

```
java.sql.PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement("insert into registraion values(?,?,?,?)");
```

Change it to below should work.:

```
java.sql.PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement("insert into registration values(?,?,?,?)");
```